# Minimal polynomial of $\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{13}\right)$

Tags: trigonometry, polynomials, minimal-polynomials

Find the Minimal polynomial of $\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{13}\right)$.
My try:

Let $$13 \theta=\pi \implies 9\theta=\pi-4\theta$$
$$\implies \cos(9\theta)=-\cos(4\theta)$$
Now Let $x=\cos(\theta)$
$$\implies 4(4x^3-3x)^3-3(4x^3-3x)=-(2(2x^2-1)^2-1) $$
$$\implies 256 x^9-576 x^7+432 x^5+16x^4-120 x^3-16 x^2+9x+2=0$$
Now how to test that this is Minimal?

Comment: If you know Chebyshev polynomials $T_7(x)+T_6(x)$ is of degree $7$ also works.

Comment: That's basically $\cos(7\theta)+\cos(6\theta)=0.$

Comment: It is $\Psi _{26} (2x)$ with degree $\frac{1}{2}\varphi (26) = 6$. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_polynomial_of_2cos(2pi/n)).

Comment: Excellent link thank u very much gary

Comment: Thanku for Andrews too :)

Comment: Yeah, you can get degree $6$ from my comment by dividing by$x-1.$ Forgot $1$ was a root of my comment.

Comment: It is a good idea to write $9\theta=\pi - 4\theta$, but you can go further by writing $7\theta=\pi - 6\theta$ (as others suggested)

Comment: Note there are some arithmetic errors: the OP's polynomial should be $256 x^9-576 x^7+432 x^5+8 x^4-120 x^3-8 x^2+9 x+1$. One way to see this isn't minimal is that $-1$ is a root; it turns out that $\frac14(1\pm\sqrt5)$ are also roots (these are $\cos\pi$, $\cos\frac\pi5$, and $\cos\frac{3\pi}5$ respectively).

Comment: @GregMartin yes thank u i agree

Answer (score 3):

Note that $\cosθ=\frac12(\zeta+\zeta^{-1})$ where $\zeta\ne -1$ is the root closest to 1 in the positive quadrant of $\zeta^{13}=-1$. This is equivalent to
$$
0=ζ^{-6}-ζ^{-5}+ζ^{-4}\mp...-ζ^{-1}+1-ζ\pm...+ζ^6.
$$
On the other hand, powers of $\cosθ$ are symmetric (Laurent) polynomials in $ζ$ with the same highest degree. Thus above equation can be expressed as a polynomial in $\cosθ$ of degree $6$.

Answer (score 3):

This is pretty standard, but I'll make a self-contained argument.

It suffices to find the minimal polynomial of $\alpha=-\cos(\frac{\pi}{13})=\cos(\pi-\frac{\pi}{13})=\cos\frac{12\pi}{13}$.

Note that $\zeta=\cos\frac{12\pi}{13}+i\sin\frac{12\pi}{13}=e^{2\pi i\frac{6}{13}}$ is a $13$-th primitive root of unity. And it can be easily shown that $\phi_{13}(x):=\sum_{i=0}^{12}x^i$ is irreducible by [applying Eisenstein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein%27s_criterion#Cyclotomic_polynomials) to $\phi_{13}(x+1)$, hence $[\mathbb Q(\zeta):\mathbb Q]=12$.

As $\alpha=\frac{\zeta + 1/\zeta}{2}$, we have $\zeta$ satisfies $\zeta^2+2\alpha\zeta +1=0$, hence $[\mathbb Q(\zeta):\mathbb Q(\alpha)]\le 2$. Since $\alpha$ is real, and $\zeta$ is not, we have $[\mathbb Q(\zeta):\mathbb Q(\alpha)]\ge 2$, hence $[\mathbb Q(\zeta):\mathbb Q(\alpha)]=2$, and finally $[\mathbb Q(\alpha):\mathbb Q]=\frac{[\mathbb Q(\zeta):\mathbb Q]}{[\mathbb Q(\zeta):\mathbb Q(\alpha)]}=6$.

To actually compute the polynomial, we may try to simplify $$\prod_{i=1}^6 (x+\frac{1}{2}(\zeta^i+\frac{1}{\zeta^i}))=\prod_{i=1}^6 (x+\frac{1}{2}(\zeta^i+\zeta^{13-i}))$$

Comment: see Reuschle page 12 https://archive.org/details/tafelncomplexer00unkngoog/page/12/mode/2up  that sextic is for $2 \cos \frac{2 \pi}{13}$   and your $2 \cos \frac{12 \pi}{13}.$  And then negate the coefficients for an odd exponent.

Comment: I don't quite understand your point, but $\cos(\frac{2\pi}{13}n)$ for $n=1, \cdots, 12$ are all Galois conjugates of each other, hence share the same minimal polynomial.

Comment: You wrote "To actually compute the polynomial, we may try to simplify."  Reuschle gives the final polynomial

Comment: Thanks for telling me! I could not read German so I have ignored the text.

Answer (score 1):

Chebyshev polynomial of the first kind $T_p(x)$ satisfies $T_p(\frac{\zeta^{i}+\zeta^{-i}}{2})=1$ for all $0\leq i\leq p-1$ where $\zeta=e^{\frac{2\pi i}{p}}$.

So, the minimal polynomial of $\cos(\frac{2\pi i}{p})$ over integers is
$$m_p(x)=\sqrt{\frac{T_p(x)-1}{x-1}}.$$

But, I don't know its series expansion.

From WA: $m_{13}(x)=-1 + 6 x + 24 x^2 - 32 x^3 - 80 x^4 + 32 x^5 + 64 x^6$

Comment: You are giving the polynomial for $\cos \frac{2 \pi}{13}$ and for  $\cos \frac{12 \pi}{13}= - \cos \frac{ \pi}{13}.$  So negate each coefficient for an odd exponent. $64 x^6 - 32 x^5 - 80 x^4 + 32 x^3 + 24 x^2 - 6x -1$